# My firefox direct me to my old domain

Tags: firefox

I have github page: [amovah.github.io](http://amovah.github.io)

I removed CNAME file, but when I open my page it show me my old domain that I added in CNAME.

Actually I know that CNAME removed successfully and my page publish on amovah.github.io not old domain.

And although It works correct in my mobile browser and another browser in my pc. You can test it.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try other browsers, if this problem doesn't happen in other browsers then Mozilla is using it's cache memory to show you the website. When you hit to load the website, it's not retrieving data from server, instead it's retrieving it from cache. So, the changes in server side is not appearing. To obtain desired result, you've to clear browser cache. To clear browser cache ...

- From the History menu, select Clear Recent History. [Or just press Ctrl + Shift + Del]
- From the Time range to clear: drop-down menu, select the desired range; to clear your entire cache, select Everything.
- Next to "Details", click the down arrow to choose which elements of the history to clear; to clear your entire cache, select all items.
- Click Clear Now.
- Exit/quit all browser windows and re-open the browser.

[source](https://kb.iu.edu/d/ahic)